# Ideas on a "defaultdict" like for javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a JS object that can accept value assignment like this without throwing any error:

```js
dict.value1.value2.value3 = 10;
```

I created a proxy object that checks if the property is in the object on a `get` trap, if it's not, it adds this property on the object with another proxy object as value.

```js
const DEFAULT_DICT_PROTECTED_PROPS = new Set(["toJSON"]);
function createDefault(target = {}) {
  return new Proxy(target, {
    get(target, p) {
      if (!(p in target) && !DEFAULT_DICT_PROTECTED_PROPS.has(p)) {
        target[p] = createDefault();
      }
      return Reflect.get(...arguments);
    },
  });
}
```

I had to "protect" the 'toJSON' prop so I could

```js
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dict))
```

Is this implementation solid enough? I feel that the `PROTECTED_PROPS` list is not perfect but I couldn't find a way to implement it generically.

Do you guys see any concern on it? Should I add some other keys as protected?

Comment: This might be more suitable for [codereview.se].

Comment: I would typically recommend not doing this at all. Proxies, and even dynamic properties nowadays, are a code smell. Hard to recommend an alternative without knowing what you’re using it for though.

Comment: @Ry- I think this is one of the very few use cases where proxies are justified (although I tend to recommend using `Map` for dictionaries). The alternative would be the `(((dict ??= {}).value1 ??= {}).value2 ??= {}).value3 = 10` pattern

Comment: looks ok, just add keys for other cases you encounter during development

Comment: @InSync I didn't know about the existence of this! i really felt that my question would fit better on a reddit post or something but [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) seems to be the perfect place